# What is second level SQL Injection

Tags: mysql, sql-injection

What is all about the second level SQL Injection.. This is with reference to the question 
[Use of parameters for mysql_query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1819377/use-of-parameters-for-mysqlquery).. and a part of one of the answers had this term...

Comment: i am not sure if i have been able to explain clearly.. but i am trying to find out if SQL Injection and the so-called second level injection are the same things?.. the link above says all about the doubt as the term has been used as a part of the answer somewhere in that answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not exactly sure but I thought it was 'defined' in the post: [Use of parameters for mysql_query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1819377/use-of-parameters-for-mysqlquery/1819417#1819417)

Excerpt (see point 2):

> `magic_quotes_gpc` automatically
>   escapes things you receive in requests
>   from clients... but it cannot detect
>   so-called second-level injections:
>
> 1. You get a malicious query from a client and store its contents in the
>      database. `magic_quotes_gpc` prevents
>      SQL injection; the malicious string
>      gets stored correctly.
> 2. Later on, you fetch this string from the database and include it in
>      another query. Now the string didn't
>      come out of a request, so
>      `magic_quotes_gpc` doesn't escape the
>      string. Voilà, SQL injection; your
>      data is now probably gone.

Here's another I've googled (http://www.osix.net/modules/article/?id=624):

> Beware that variables inside a stored
>   procedure aren't always immune to SQL
>   Injection either. If the stored
>   procedure contains constructs that add
>   a second level of parsing, such as
>   EXEC on a string in MS SQL Server, you
>   will have to handle metacharacters
>   again. This time inside the stored
>   procedure.

Answer (score 0):

If you just never assume ANY data is "safe" to put into a query, then you shouldn't have any problems with SQL Injection. Even if *<insert religious icon>* him/herself hands you piece of data and tells you to insert it into SQL query... you should still verify it! xD

It's a good idea to try to always use [Parameterized Statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection#Parameterized_statements) when executing queries. That way the database driver itself is responsible for escaping potentially harmful data, vastly reducing the risk of any type of SQL injection.